# migration of hashed passwords to KeyCloak Red Hat Single Sign-On 7.5.0.GA

Tags: keycloak, sha1, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I want to migrate my user passwords to keycloack Red Hat Single Sign-On 7.5.0.GA. The passwords in my current user store are hashed with SHA1 with 1 iteration and no salt.
I am attempting to migrate the data using the following API

```
url/auth/admin/realms/demo/users/{{userid}}

Body

{
    "credentials": [
        {
            "algorithm": "pbkdf1-sha1",
            "secretData": "b017da8c710a97862be7a686440c91464cddd905",
            "type": "password",
           "hashIterations": 1,
            "salt": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

The API request goes through without any exception.

The password is Login345. When i try to login it says invalid loginid /password.
Can anyone advise on how this can be achieved

Answer (score 2):

Hi in case any has a similar requirement. i followed the steps documented in

https://github.com/nicolabeghin/keycloak-sha1-salted and was able to migrate password from OAM to keycloack